# Clearing the chart causes memory leak?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks

I am trying to redraw JFreeChart series every a few seconds with new data. Redrawing is doing in own thread. Everything is working fine but clearing the series causes weird memory leak.

I am not sure if the problem comes from [sleeping the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160643/java-memory-behavior-different-with-thread-sleep) or there's any bug in the clear() method.

This is complete sample code (problematic line in method SampleDataFeed):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.time.FixedMillisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeriesCollection;

public class sample1 {
    private static OHLCSeries series1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // window
                JFrame wnd = new JFrame();
                wnd.setVisible(true);
                wnd.setSize(800, 500);
                wnd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                // chart series
                OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("Test");
                OHLCSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new OHLCSeriesCollection();
                seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
                series1 = seriesCollection.getSeries(0);

                // chart
                final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(null, "Time", "Price", seriesCollection, false);
                chart.getXYPlot().setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

                // chart panel
                final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
                chartPanel.setMaximumDrawHeight(2000);
                chartPanel.setMaximumDrawWidth(3000);
                wnd.add(chartPanel);

                // chart data feeding thread
                new DataFeedingThread().start();
            }
        });

    }

    private static class DataFeedingThread implements Runnable {
        private Thread t;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // run recursively
            while (true) {

                // feed the chart with random data
                SampleDataFeed();

                // what 1 second before next run
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // feed the chart with random data
        private void SampleDataFeed() {
            series1.clear(); // -----> This line causes memory leak! If I'd comment it, everything is Ok.
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, i);
                FixedMillisecond fm = new FixedMillisecond(cal.getTime());
                series1.add(fm, randInt(95, 105), randInt(105, 110), randInt(90, 95), randInt(95, 105));
            }
        }

        // return random integer
        private int randInt(int min, int max) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            return randomNum;
        }

        public void start() {
            if (t == null) {
                t = new Thread(this);
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

JFreeChart version: 1.0.19

Compiler options: none

Memory usage **without clearing ~15-30 MB**:

[image]

Memory usage **with clearing ~430MB and raising**:

[image]

Comment: I ran your example program and it didn't run out of memory.  It maxed at ~1.3G but GC kept it to that.

Comment: 1.3G is too much, don't you think?

Comment: It could be a lot, but it's not leaking in the classic sense.   Since the memory is being reclaimed by the GC, you probably just have too low of heap.  I could just decrease my MaxHeap size (Xmx), but there will be a minimum required number for 100 of the series created.

Comment: Hm... sorry I don't undestand anything of what you wrote. :(

Comment: "leaking in the classic sense" would mean that there is no value of -Xmx that would be high enough:  The heap would continue to grow until it hit the limit.  @JohnVint is saying that there _is_ a limit that's high enough, and therefore it's not a memory leak, it's just how much memory your program needs.

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks, good explanation. Martin, a memory leak occurs when your memory never gets freed up.  Typically you'd see a *GC overhead limit reached*.  In this case, it is just taking up a lot of memory but not leaking.

Comment: @JohnVint Yes, you're right in memory leak definition. But if the 1.3 GB of RAM is not freed, why is it for there? I must repeat that the memory is heaping when I do clear() the chart and when don't, it is not heaping. According your definition it should be opposited.

Comment: @Martin So I looked in the code and all clear does is null out the data found in the dataset, that should be fine.  Then it fires whatever listeners are attached to event changing.  That may be causing issues.  But considering it works fine for me and fails for you it's either 1.  Your system needs to define higher memory so that the max it can reach isn't or  2. You have a different version of JFreechart which does have a leak.

Comment: That being said, since I cannot recreate the issue, I cannot really identify what the cause is.  Maybe include version of JFreechart and the VM args if you are having them set

Comment: @JohnVint Ok I've added these info+profilling to the original post.

Comment: I would post your concerns in the [JFreeChart Forums](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=80c806e50ac7e3465cf90bb8cc7a3f14). David Gilbert is very good at answering your concerns relatively quickly. There might even be a post there related to that issue. There is also different chart types that allow for real-time updates. So, I would use those instead.

Comment: @Martin Do you know what your max heap size is?  I would like to recreate the OOM error.

Comment: @JohnVint
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 130023424                           {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2067791872                          {product}

Comment: @JohnVint I think it should be 2GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that removings all series of collection and then add new prepared serie with data is solution for this (bug?).

Here's my new code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.time.FixedMillisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeriesCollection;

public class sample1 {
    private static final OHLCSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new OHLCSeriesCollection();
    private static final DataFeedingThread dataFeedingThread = new DataFeedingThread();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAll();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAll() {
        // window
        JFrame wnd = new JFrame();
        wnd.setVisible(true);
        wnd.setSize(800, 500);
        wnd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // chart series
        seriesCollection.addSeries(new OHLCSeries("Test"));

        // chart
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(null, "Time", "Price", seriesCollection, false);
        chart.getXYPlot().setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

        // chart panel
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setMaximumDrawHeight(2000);
        chartPanel.setMaximumDrawWidth(3000);
        wnd.add(chartPanel);

        // chart data feeding thread
        dataFeedingThread.start();      
    }


    public static void setOHLCSeries(OHLCSeries series) {
        seriesCollection.removeAllSeries();
        seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
    }

    private static class DataFeedingThread implements Runnable {
        private Thread t;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // run recursively
            while (true) {

                // feed the chart with random data
                SampleDataFeed();

                // what 1 second before next run
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // feed the chart with random data
        private void SampleDataFeed() {
            OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("test");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, i);
                FixedMillisecond fm = new FixedMillisecond(cal.getTime());
                series.add(fm, randInt(95, 105), randInt(105, 110), randInt(90, 95), randInt(95, 105));
            }
            setOHLCSeries(series);
        }

        // return random integer
        private int randInt(int min, int max) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            return randomNum;
        }

        public void start() {
            if (t == null) {
                t = new Thread(this);
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the code above I remove all the series in chart and add new serie (with prepared data). That's all and everything's working fine.

Here is the memory profilling: 
[image]

As you can see, all the application doesn't consume more than 110 MB.

**UPDATE 1:**

In fact the example above didn't solve the problem. There are a lot of situations where this bug occurres. I've had many hours testing and finding the final solution of the memory leak problem.
The only one posibility is this can be [#1111 bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/bugs/1111/) in JFreeGhart. It is open longer than a year.  [Mr. Gilber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592874/david-gilbert) can you fix this problem, please? I am willing to pay you for it if it will all work anytime soon.

Thanks.